# How do I find out which version of gems is suitible for which versions of ruby and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is there somewhere I can go to get a comparison of ruby to gems to rails?

for example

```
ruby  |  gems   |    rails
1.8   |   1.7   |    2.9
1.9   |   2.0   |    3.0
1.9   |   2.2   |    3.1
```

That would relay help

Comment: Ruby version 1.9.x    with rails 3.2.x

Comment: That depends on the specific gem you are asking about and will hopefully be in the gem's documentation.

Comment: Install the latest Ruby and Rails. Attempt to install the Gem. Downgrade as reported by missing dependencies, but only if you *really* need the Gem in question. Caveat: If you have a hosting provider and you're not interested in moving, use their versions.

Comment: If you use Bundler and each gem’s dependencies are declared correctly you will never need to do this.

Comment: I do as both @meagar and @AndrewMarshall recommend, start with the latest, and let those gems that are essential complain if they can't find the needed revision. Use `gem install needed_gem -v1.0`, replacing "needed_gem" with the gem to install, and "-v1.0" with whatever version you need.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ruby 1.9.x. 
because Ruby on Rails 4.0 release soon. (maybe 2013).
RoR4.0 must be need only 1.9.x 
:-)

I strongly recommend lastest version of Ruby, Rails